# How to retrieve ID elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, object, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

Could you help me to retrieve one of the ArrayList elements? Precondition is below.

Product class has three properties(**productID**, product name, price), so throw the below values in the constructor and create an object.

```
Product chocolate = new Product("5", "chocolate", 12);
```

Department class has two properties(department ID, department name), so throw the below values in the constructor and create an object.
Department class also has "addProduct" method, so add the above chocolate object in the grocery department.

```
Department groceries= new Department("2", "groceries");
groceries.addProduct(chocolate);
```

Directory class has an ArrayList, so added groceries department in the ArrayList using "addDepartemnt" method.

```
Directory directory = new Directory();
directory.addDepartment(groceries);
```

Suppose there are multiple products. Is there any way to retrieve "**productID**" from the directory ArrayList? I am going to loop the directory ArrayList and compare the IDs and user input ID, and it it's mactched, i want to retrieve all the product information (productID, product name, price).

```
public class Department implements Catalog {
    private ArrayList<Catalog> subCatalogList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
    private String departmentId;
    private String departmentName;

    public Department(String departmentId, String departmentName){
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public void addProduct(Catalog catalog){
        subCatalogList.add(catalog);
    }

public class Directory implements Catalog {
    private ArrayList<Catalog> catalogDirectory = new ArrayList<Catalog>();

    public void addDepartment(Catalog department){
        catalogDirectory.add(department);
    }

public class Product implements Catalog {
    private String prodId;
    private String prodName;
    private double price;

    public Product(String prodId, String prodName, double price){
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.prodName = prodName;
        this.price = price;
    }
```

Comment: As I see, one directory can have multiple departments, where each department could have multiple products?

Comment: not enough information given. I don't understand what the question is

Comment: @Ismail, Yes, that's right. one directory can have multiple departments, where each department could have multiple products. 
And I want to retrieve a product information from the directory which productID is matched with int value which a user inputs.

Comment: @mercredi is there a list of products inside the department class?

Comment: Yes, Department class has a list of products,  and Directory class also has a list which added Department classes object.
I will modify my question as code is messy here.

Comment: @mercredi, with this structure to retrieve a product by its ID you will have to answer a few questions: in which directory the product is? what if more than one directory have the same product? in which department the product is? what if more than one department have the same product? Sure you can do what you want with nested loops,  but I'd suggest you changing the structure. A simple rush change could be using a `Map` to store products where key is a product ID and value is the product itself. And then in`Department` you could just store a list of product IDs.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "retrieve `productId`"? Do you mean to select a product by product ID? Get a list of all the product IDs? Something else?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov, directory is only one which has multiple departments, and departments have products. However, products are never duplicated in all the departments. 
Ok, using Map sounds reasonable than ArrayList if i need to use nested loop. Thanks, Pavel.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, Get a list of all the product IDs using loop, then compare them  and int value which a user inputs, then print out the product information if the ID is matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve his using Java streams, for example for a given `productID` and a given `directory`:

```
Product productToFind = (Product) directory.getCatalogDirectory ().stream()
.flatMap( department -> ((Department) department).getSubCatalogList().stream())
.filter( product -> ((Product)product).getProdId().equals(productID)).findFirst().get();
```

First, you gather all the products from a directory in one list using `flatMap`, and then you filter on it using the given `productID`.

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to add `getters` to your classes like bellow:

```
public class Department implements Catalog {
    private ArrayList<Catalog> subCatalogList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
    private String departmentId;
    private String departmentName;

    public Department(String departmentId, String departmentName){
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public void addProduct(Catalog catalog){
        subCatalogList.add(catalog);
    }

    public ArrayList<Catalog> getSubCatalogList(){
        return this.subCatalogList;
    }
}

public class Directory implements Catalog {
    private ArrayList<Catalog> catalogDirectory = new ArrayList<Catalog>();

    public void addDepartment(Catalog department){
        catalogDirectory.add(department);
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Catalog> getCatalogDirectory (){
        return this.catalogDirectory ;
    }
}

public class Product implements Catalog {
    private String prodId;
    private String prodName;
    private double price;

    public Product(String prodId, String prodName, double price){
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.prodName = prodName;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getProdId (){
        return this.prodId;
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
@Test
public void test(){

Directory directory=new Directory();
Department dep =new Department("department1", "departmentName");
dep.subCatalogList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Product("idtofind", "hello name", 32)));
directory.catalogDirectory = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dep));
String productID="idtofind";
Product productToFind = (Product) directory.getCatalogDirectory ().stream()
        .flatMap(department -> ((Department) department).getSubCatalogList().stream())
        .filter(product -> ((Product)product).getProdId().equals(productID)).findFirst().get();
System.out.println(productToFind.prodName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ismail, I didn't know about Java streams.
However, directory has multiple department objects (, such as food, stationary..etc), so 'department.getSubCatalogList()' gets an error. Is there anyway to fix it?

(chocolate is in food department)

Comment: I think you are missing to add to your classes getters, because the classes fields are private, we can't have access to it without getter, check the answer edit.

Comment: Getters were created for the lists and productID in each classs. Seems 'department' after lambda is valuable type, so i changed to Department, but still gets the same error.

Comment: The no problem with 'department'. I see the issue here is; you are using a parent type 'Catalog' to declare the lists, so for department and product, the compiler cannot recognize the getters. What you need is to cast the variables. I will edit the lambda expression with cast). see the lambda expression again.

Comment: Thanks again, but I got an error _The method flatMap(Function<? super Catalog,? extends Stream<? extends R>>) in the type Stream<Catalog> is not applicable for the arguments (Department)"_. Is this because "Catalog" is an interface? The list is declared as "Catalog" as the department list stores two objects (Product and Department).

Comment: @mercredi I think I messed up with the variables cast, now I've edited the lambda expression, you can find above the required modification. I have reimplemented your case with my answer in my local environment, normally it should work.

Comment: This time, no error in the code and all the getters are auto-generated. However, once i ran the code, i got a ClassCastException from the following row: `.filter(product ->((Product)product).getProdId().equals("9")).findFirst().get();`

Comment: Are you sure you have a list of Products inside the departments?
I have edited the answer with my test case.

Comment: Yes, i do, but actually when i use methods to add products to the directory/department ArrayLists, i got the error.
`directory.addDepartment(food);
food.addProduct(chocolate);`

However, if i use ArrayList to add departments/products like your test case, it is working as expected!!
`dep.subCatalogList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Product("idtofind", "hello name", 32)));
directory.catalogDirectory = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dep));`

Thanks a lot for your help!!!